# creating styled forms with html and css

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm tryin to write a form in html and css.my knowledge in html and css is not enough.i need help in creating [this](http://pasteboard.co/1pdI3W1O.jpg) form.anybody have any idea how can i create this?please refer to jsfiddle.net
thanks.

Comment: Please paste some code here, also you could not ask for ideas. Instead you ask here when you stuck somewhere.

Comment: acctualy i can't create this form, so i called for help? i want exact thsi form.

Comment: use table for form elements of about two columns and  about nine rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap. This is the best option as it has inbuilt styles.

[Boostrap Link For forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: i don't know much about css library.how can i do it with bootstrap?

Comment: Just add Bootstrap.css . you can download it from internet and they had gave tutorials with each section
(http://getbootstrap.com/css/) @Andre